# Pass a pattern as a function parameter?

Tags: rust, matching

I'm wondering is there a way to pass a pattern as a function parameter.

I have:

```
pub enum KEYWORD {
    assign(ASSIGN),
    symbol(SYMBOL),
    illegal
}

pub enum ASSIGN { /* some enums */ }
pub enum SYMBOL { /* some enums */ }
```

Now, I know I can use `match!` or one I made `expect!` macro to match my key `l.key()` so:

```
macro_rules! expect(($e:expr, $p:pat) => (
    match $e {
        $p => { true },
        _ => { false }
    }
));

expect!(l.key(), KEYWORD::symbol(_));
```

However, I need many more cases, where I need to pass `KEYWORD::symbol(_)` as function parameter, eg:

```
impl l {
    pub fn expect_as_func(&self, KEYWORD) { /* some code */ }
}

l.expect_as_func(KEYWORD::symbol(_));
```

But this `l.expect_as_func(KEYWORD::symbol(_));` is wrong, as I'm not using a value, but a pattern.

I tried using `proc_macro` and `TokenStream`:

```
pub fn expect(&mut self, patt: TokenStream) -> bool {
    match &self {
        patt => { true },
        _ => { false }
    }
}
```

but this doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From an ergonomics perspective, you could try to implement functions `is_assign`, `is_symbol`, `is_illegal` on your enum:

```
impl KEYWORD {
    fn is_assign(&self) -> bool {
        match self {
            KEYWORD::assign(_) => true,
            _ => false,
        }
    }
    // and so on
}
```

Now, as all this becomes tedious, you could e.g. create a macro that generates these functions:

```
macro_rules! generate_is(($variant: pat, $fn_name: ident) => {
    fn $fn_name(&self) -> bool {
        match self {
            $variant => true,
            _ => false,
        }
    }
});

impl KEYWORD {
    generate_is!(KEYWORD::assign(_), is_assign);
    generate_is!(KEYWORD::symbol(_), is_symbol);
    generate_is!(KEYWORD::illegal, is_illegal);
}
```

This way, callers simply say `keyword.is_assign()` (or similar).

Then, on top of that, you could try to invent something that automatically generates the `is_...`-functions from your enum. (Possibly via a procedural macro.)

Answer (score 0):

I would say that fundamentally the pattern is not something that is supposed to get passed as a function argument into the function: instead a concrete instance of the type should be passed.

Anyways if the context of this task does really need it you could implement the whole function as a `TokenSteam` with a pattern inside via the `proc_macro`. Something like the following:

```
let tokens = quote! {
    pub fn expect(&mut self) -> bool {
        match &self {
            #patt => { true },
            _ => { false }
       }
    }
};
```